# Specifying background size as a percentage of the bg image's size

Tags: css, mobile, svg, background-image

Is there some way of specifying the CSS background size as a percentage of the background image's size. With pure CSS (even CSS3 ) it seems impossible, but maybe there's some clever way using other CSS properties/html (This only has to work with SVGs and on mobile).

Comment: @Pete background-size allows you to specify a pixel size or size relative to the element that's being styled - no ability to size relative to the original image

Comment: @pete I have a large sprite sheet which may change in size in future, but (in order to avoid bluriness in android browser) the SVG is deliberately twice as big as it needs to be, so I want to be able to say `background-size: [50% of the image size]`; if I specify pixel values then I will have to alter these every time the spritesheet grows (I'm leaving lots of empty space in the sprite to mediate this, but experience tells me that eventually spritesheets do grow)

Answer (score -2):

can you try this way

```
background-size: 200px;
background-size: 200px 100px;
background-size: 200px 100px, 400px 200px;
background-size: auto 200px;
background-size: 50% 25%;
background-size: contain;
background-size: cover;
```